# Use getText() and setText() Method in one XML for Android

Tags: android, xml, gettext, settext

I'm trying to create an xml which gets me the text of the the editText field. Although it works but I am only getting the typed in text for only the last field.
This is my code:

```
TextView textOut;
EditText getInput;

TextView textOut1;
EditText getInput1;

TextView textOut2;
EditText getInput2;

TextView textOut3;
EditText getInput3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.account);

    textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    getInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textOut.setText(getInput.getText());
        }
    });
    textOut1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    getInput1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button ok1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    ok1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textOut1.setText(getInput1.getText());
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to get the text for all the typed text fields. I have four field ( I have only shown two in the code)

Is there anyway in which I can get the typed in text for all the editText field?

Thank you.

Edit:

```
 TextOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    getInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textOut1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    getInput1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textOut.setText(getInput.getText());
        }
    });
```

Comment: on button click you want to get all text fields?

Comment: thinksteep yes, but I only get the input from the last editText.

Answer (score 1):

After you get the the value in the text field you have to store it in a String variable in order to access it. You're calling getText() on your editText but why are you not calling toString() also? Change your second onClick to this.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       String s =  getInput1.getText().toString();
       textOut1.setText(s);


    }
});
```

Comment: I still have the same result.

Comment: You have two buttons, ok and ok1. They both have the same reference IDs, trying fixing that.

Comment: They are the same button, but I can't seem keep their variable name the same, as I get an error.

Comment: Let me guess, is it a "Duplicate variable" error? Create one instance of Button ok, inflate it using findViewById(R.id.submit) and just set one listener for it. You're creating a new instance of a listener for the same button, I'm sure that's apart of your problem

Comment: I did this: textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
  getInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  textOut1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
  getInput1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
  Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
  ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    textOut.setText(getInput.getText());
   }
  });

Comment: But now I only the get typed in data from the first field.

Comment: That looks about correct, and if you want to update more than one textView ie textOut, textOut1 etc. You can do so from within the scope of that onClick. Does it work? Add in the code to update the last TextView as well and you should be fine. textOut1.setText.......

Comment: I only get the data for the first field, not the second 'textOut1'

Comment: edit your original post and put up the code you have now, I'll have a look

Comment: I put the code up. I think I may have to change the textOut.setText(getInput.getText());

Comment: oh I added a new line: textOut1.setText(getInput1.getText()); it seems to work now.

Comment: You have two textViews, textOut and textOut1 and you said you wanted to update them both, then why haven't you updated textOut1 also?

Comment: I updated it now, and it seems to work. Thank you for your help :)